# Dual space of space of sequnce converging to 0 is isomorphic to $l_1$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $A=$ space of sequence converging to 0 =$ (c_0,||.||_{\infty})$ and $B=l^1$

For each $x=(x_n)\in B$ we can define

$\phi_x:A\to \mathbb R$ as

$\phi_x(y)=\sum x_ny_n$

we can define $\psi:B\to A^*$

as $\psi(x)=\phi_x$

I had shown $||\phi_x||=||x||$ and $\psi$ is one one linear transformation . How to show onto ?

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: did you try to do this? if you have $l \in A^*$, you want to find an $x$ so that $l = \varphi_x$. ok, what can $x$ be? well, you know that $\varphi_x((1,0,0,\dots)) = x_1$, so if $l = \varphi_x$ for some $x$, then $x_1 = l(1,0,0,\dots)$. Similarly, you would have to have $x_n = l(0,\dots,0,1,0,0,\dots)$, with the $1$ in the $n^{th}$ position. So only question now is whether this $(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ works. Did you try this problem at all? You can/should show your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f \in A^*$ be arbitrary. Let $(e_n)_n$ be the canonical vectors in $c_0$. For $y \in c_0$ we have $y = \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_ne_n$ so
$$f(y) = f\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_ne_n\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_nf(e_n) = \phi_x(y)$$

where $x = (f(e_n))_{n}$.

We indeed have $x \in \ell^1$. Write $f(e_n) = |f(e_n)|e^{i\theta_n}$. Then for every $N \in \Bbb{N}$ holds
$$\sum_{n=1}^N |f(e_n)| = |f(e^{-i\theta_1}, \ldots, e^{-i\theta_n}, 0, 0, \ldots)| \le \|f\|\|(e^{-i\theta_1}, \ldots, e^{-i\theta_n}, 0, 0, \ldots)\|_\infty = \|f\|$$
so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(e_n)| < +\infty$.

Comment: "Namely"? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @mathworker21 Maybe not the best use, removed.

Comment: okay, $+1$, I didn't see the $e^{i\theta}$ trick within $30$ seconds